# Web technology for a first small web project

Tags: django, frameworks

I'm a C++ developer with basic Python skills. Here's the task, a friend of mine is running a small company and he asked me if I can make a website for him. I have no real deadline so I think it's a perfect opportunity to try sth new and do some web development.

User has to be able to add photos, change texts ect.

Do you think that Django would be an overkill for this kind of project? I have no experience with it. Perhaps I should try to customize some blog engine or Google Sites?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may be interested in Google App Engine ([http://code.google.com/appengine](http://code.google.com/appengine/)) which recently exhibited a rise in popularity. The application runs on Google's servers, eliminating the need to maintain Apache and worry about up-time. You basically get a Django-based solution with a data store, with an SDK which allows you to conveniently develop an application on your desktop and then upload it to appspot.com for everyone to use.

The documentation is great, and even if you eventually decide not to use it, the [tutorial](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/gettingstarted/) is excellent for getting you up to speed on Python and webapp design. There is also a [codelab](http://code.google.com/p/google-app-engine-codelab/downloads/list) which contains a simple Wiki example.

Comment: Is that already public? Or still in real beta? ( not like gmail that's been in beta for years ) but in real beta where you can't still put a production environment there?

Comment: Google is planning to provide production environments when they feel the product and the market are ready for each other. It is probably going to be a paid service where you pay according to the amount of resources (CPU, network traffic) you use.

Answer (score 3):

If you need to set up quickly a **very simple website**, **Wordpress** can be the perfect choice.

Wordpress is born as a blogging platform, but in the newer version you can manage pages, contact form and so on. And you can find good plugins to expand its capabilities.
The administration interface of wordpress is clean and easy to use, the page or article editor is simple and powerful. Add an image in a post or in a page is easy and intuitive as in no other opensource CMS I've seen.

Answer (score 2):

Django is a pretty flexible framework, it tends to scale well both up and down. It may be overkill to have to learn the whole API for just a simple site, but if you're looking to learn something new, and have some time to spare, then it's a fun platform to learn and work from. My suggestion would be to install the API and have a play around with it, read the [Django book](http://www.djangobook.com/) and see how you get on.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe before diving into Joomla or Django a first step should be working with the technologies in a raw, pure way.   Create a simple web page that excutes some server side script (python? php?) that retrieves data from a mySQL database and displays it.   Throw in a little javascript too.   Just so that you feel comfortable with the bare-bones fundamentals.

Then when you dive into the big frameworks and libraries, they won't seem so magical.

Answer (score 1):

If you're really asking what the best tool for the job is, then you are going to have to give a little more detail than "first small web project." If what you are asking is more along the lines of you want to learn web application development and what you already know is C++ and python so what would be a good web application stack where you can leverage your current skillset, then here are some more suggestions.

Django is pretty cool. Every one has already talked about it here. As mentioned earlier, the google app engine is sort of based on Django.

Also, consider [zope](http://www.zope.org/) which is another python based web application container.

If you wanted to leverage your C++ knowledge instead, then consider [Wt](http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt).

Why don't you take a look at the hello world examples for all three and decide which one looks the most interesting to you?

Answer (score 0):

There are a multitude of website frameworks and kits that you could go with as opposed to starting development work from the ground up.  It really depends on what kind of technology you want to go with, and how comfortable you feel with the language's potential.  As mentioned above, there are things like [Joomla](http://www.joomla.org/), and If you want to stick to PhP frameworks, you could also use [Drupal](http://drupal.org/), which has a ton of documentation and support, and is relatively easy to understand.

If you want to venture into the Microsoft realm, you could look into [DotNetNuke](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/).  It too is much like Drupal and Joomla, so it's a nice CMS framework, which you might feel more comfortable with since ASP.Net is based off of a programming language as opposed to a a scripting language, unlike Classic ASP or PhP.  If you're going to go the Microsoft route, I also recommend taking a look at their [BizSpark](http://www.microsoft.com/bizspark/Default.aspx) developer program - but that's more dependent on how serious your friend is on running his site as a business.

Then you also have a lot of things offered up by [Google](http://code.google.com/), such as their charts and visualizations -- which doesn't seems like something you're looking for, but for future reference, or cool little things like a map mashup.

It really depends on how much you're willing to learn and how much time you have and sometimes not having a rough deadline is the worst possible thing that could happen. Naturally everything starts to take longer.  By the time you're done, the tech is either out of date, or you've taken so long that the business plan has changed.

Answer (score 0):

using django it is easy, there is already an application for photo albums available at http://code.google.com/p/django-photologue/ it becomes with tagging too and maybe you just need to add some jquery effects to get done your site.

To get this done you just create a django project, add the applications to your settings, configure your urls and templates, and thats it.

Also i f you need a small version you can just use this code as a base of your new app.

have fun with django!!

sergio

Answer (score 0):

[Pylons](http://pylonshq.com) is an excellent Python web framework based on WSGI standard. It has ported many of the features of Ruby on Rails so is great for rapid development.

I've been using it for a few years now combined with SQLAlchemy for my database layer and I've found it perfect for development of all my web sites.

It is easily good enough for [production sites](http://wiki.pylonshq.com/display/pylonscommunity/Sites+Using+Pylons) too.

The one downside I've found is slight complications getting it deployed on shared hosting but as long as you have shell access to your host, you should be fine.

Answer (score -2):

You may try to install and customize Joomla (http://www.joomla.org/) It's full of stuff, easy to use and easy to customize also.

Answer (score -2):

Everybody reaches for a framework, but, assuming this is running on Apache, why not just server side includes, and, since you have Python experience, Python CGI scripts that emit JSON for use in the UI by Javascript.  By going with CGI/SSI you defer your decisions about framework and/or templating system until later, when you have more experience under your belt, but you should be able to get a reasonable amount of re-use of whatever Python code you write.

Answer (score -2):

I'll cast my vote for Drupal (http://www.drupal.org)

Answer (score -2):

I think  [LOVDbyLess](http://lovdbyless.com/)  might do exactly what you want. If all you need is basic blog and photo upload and a simple SNS, then check out this Ruby-on-Rails open-source thing. It's been evolving with new features and is pretty easy to set up.